# [VSTO Word]How to get the range after PasteAndFormat?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have the code as follow:

```cs
    Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection;
    Word.Range range = selection.Range;
    MessageBox.Show("Range :" + range.Text);
    range.Copy();
    range.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatPlainText);
    if (range == null)
        MessageBox.Show("The Range is null currently");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Range :" + range.Text);
```

For instance, create a new Word document and input "ABC", if I select the entire "ABC" and run the program, the range won't be changed, but if I select a single character and run the program, the range will be null, why does this happen? I have to edit the range furtherly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and now I can get the range after PasteAndFormat.

```cs
    Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection;
    int start = selection.Start;
    int count = selection.Text.Length;
    selection.Copy();
    selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatPlainText);
    int newStart = selection.Start;
    selection.SetRange(start, newStart);
    Word.Range range = selection.Range;
    if (range == null)
        MessageBox.Show("The Range is null currently");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Range :" + range.Text);
```

I guess maybe the "Range" is a kind of format, it will be clear after PasteAndFormat(wdFormatPlainText).